# Desynchonization between realm collection notification and collection view count

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, realm

I'm using Realm in my project to write realtime data coming from an API and populating a UICollectionView in the same time. To achieve that I've been using Realm's Collection Notification (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications) to observe insertions. The problem I'm having is that I always get the following error when I'm using more than one section in the collection view:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of items in section 2.  The number of items contained in an
>   existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of
>   items contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus
>   the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I have 3 sections in the collection view that I need to refresh each time I receive a new item from the API. It works perfectly when I have 1 section but result in a crash when I have 3 sections. To do so, I have an array of `NotificationToken` and I observe new insertions as such:

```c
 internal func observeResults(results: Results<SJResult>, section: Int) {
      notificationTokens.append(results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        switch changes {
          case .initial:
            collectionView.reloadData()
            break
          case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
              collectionView.insertItems(at: insertions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) })
              collectionView.deleteItems(at: deletions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) })
              collectionView.reloadItems(at: modifications.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) })
            })
            break
          case .error(let error):
            fatalError("\(error)")
            break
        }
      })
    }
```

I'm writing the result in a background queue like that:

```c
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
  for (index, group) in groups.enumerated() {
    let result = Item(group: group)

    if let realm = try? Realm() {
      do {
        try realm.write {
          realm.add(result)
        }
      } catch let exception {
        print("Can't write result: \(exception)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And that's how I specify the number of items in each section:

```c
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return results(leg: section).count // Query the table to get the results I want to display
}
```

It seems that when the collection view is inserting new elements (in `collectionView.performBatchUpdates`), there is new item that are sometimes written on the database `realm.add(result)` in the same time, which result in a crash as the total number of items has changed between the start and the end of the update. I managed to avoid the crash by writing synchronously `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync`, which lead to some performance issues. I really would like to write any new item asynchronously but I can't figure out why it crashes. Does anyone has an idea of what's going on and how I can improve that please?

Answer (score 3):

The updates need to be applied to your `collectionView` in the same order as they're defined in the `.update` case: deletions first, insertions second, modifications third. So your `performBatchUpdates` block should look like this:

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
  collectionView.deleteItems(at: deletions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) })
  collectionView.insertItems(at: insertions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) })
  collectionView.reloadItems(at: modifications.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) })
})
```

Comment: I've tried your answer. seems this doesn't matter, still got the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling with the same problem right now. My latest theory to explain why it works perfectly fine with one section and starts crashing with more then one section is as follows:
The collection view checks for the number of items in the sections at the beginning of the animations and again at the end to catch consistency errors. As long as you have one section, changes to the results will generate sequences of notifications, each starting a new performBatchUpdates that will keep everything perfectly synced.
When you have more than one section, with their own notifications attached to different results, you start having interleaved sequences of notifications that start their own performBatchUpdates, and more importantly check the counts of all the sections at the end of each animation.
That is probably why you and me are having these problems. We have individual notifications per section, but their work affects the whole collection view sections, including previously started in flight animations and their end-of-flight checks. I do not have a solution for this problem yet.

Comment: You may also find some possible workaround in the third comment of this blog post: https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2016/04/29/uicollectionview-invalid-number-of-items-crash-issue/#comment-3213091626

Comment: @nonouf what version of Realm are you using?